# Announcement: new mobile ads

Tags: discussion

We wanted to let you know that we are currently testing some new ads on the mobile version of Ask Different. They are shown in two places right now: the bottom of the home page, and the question page (between the first and second answers, as on Stack Overflow). Right now you'll only see them if:

1. You're viewing the mobile version of the web site
2. You're on an iOS device
3. You have less than 200 rep (i.e. don't have the [reduced ads privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads)).

This is only a test, and we're interested in your feedback. Obviously, nobody *loves* ads, but we're hoping these are unobtrusive enough (especially for high-rep users, who will see less of them) and at least somewhat interesting to justify their existence. Stack Exchange will always remain free, so we have to experiment with some small ways to pay for the sites' upkeep.

If we don't see good enough results from these ads, we'll shut them off in a few weeks.

[image]

Comment: Cheers for the heads-up.